# OCR with OpenCV and Tesseract giving wrong results

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm new to image processing/computer vision and trying to read the characters of a sudoku image. I think my cv part is working correctly as the image I am passing to tesseract is what I would expect, however tesseract is giving me very strange results.
[Image I am passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76LoP.jpg)

Is giving me "ne)" instead of "5".

I have the following code to deal with extraction:

```
char* extract_value(Mat img)
{
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    char* outText;

    ocr->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
    ocr->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
    
    if (ocr->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize Tesseract." << std::endl;
        return outText;
    }

    ocr->SetImage(img.data, img.cols, img.rows, 3, img.step);

    outText = ocr->GetUTF8Text();

    ocr->End();
    delete ocr;
    return outText;
}
```

Quite confusing and any tips would be much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should start with reading tesseract documentation and understand the parameters you used for OCR. With the right parameters, you can get the correct result.